# Select random name from the JSON response in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In the response body I have the following JSON, which contains and id and as a child element a name and I want to select random name and its corresponding id every time I run my test, how to do it?

May be through a post processer or json extractor, I am new to JMeter.

```
 {
    "entities": {
        "chairs": {
            "a99a921e-9ced-43eb-8521-a8e972c5afee": {
                "id": "a99a921e-9ced-43eb-8521-a8e972c5afee",
                "accountId": "02a39418-2936-4696-9f3f-02f503128ac7",
                "description": null,
                "isActive": true,
                "pmsId": "5079767850816079897",
                "name": "PranayOP",
                "createdAt": "2021-03-18T17:46:53.253Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-03-18T17:46:53.253Z",
                "deletedAt": null
            },
            "eb125d3a-739f-479c-b803-dbffb6a871d0": {
                "id": "eb125d3a-739f-479c-b803-dbffb6a871d0",
                "accountId": "02a39418-2936-4696-9f3f-02f503128ac7",
                "description": null,
                "isActive": true,
                "pmsId": "-3332289498024566266",
                "name": "OVERFLOW",
                "createdAt": "2021-03-16T00:42:35.115Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-03-16T00:42:35.115Z",
                "deletedAt": null
            },
            "36891051-1edf-46ea-a167-68d39a8a70f5": {
                "id": "36891051-1edf-46ea-a167-68d39a8a70f5",
                "accountId": "02a39418-2936-4696-9f3f-02f503128ac7",
                "description": null,
                "isActive": true,
                "pmsId": "-4453494259576621766",
                "name": "OP55",
                "createdAt": "2021-03-20T02:19:00.494Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-03-20T02:19:00.494Z",
                "deletedAt": null
            },
            "85a2564e-7cd1-4e69-be5d-a979b5e56cd5": {
                "id": "85a2564e-7cd1-4e69-be5d-a979b5e56cd5",
                "accountId": "02a39418-2936-4696-9f3f-02f503128ac7",
                "description": null,
                "isActive": true,
                "pmsId": "8283273375660346038",
                "name": "OP02",
                "createdAt": "2021-03-16T00:42:34.832Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-03-16T00:42:34.832Z",
                "deletedAt": null
            }
        }
    },
    "result": [
        "a99a921e-9ced-43eb-8521-a8e972c5afee",
        "eb125d3a-739f-479c-b803-dbffb6a871d0",
        "36891051-1edf-46ea-a167-68d39a8a70f5",
        "85a2564e-7cd1-4e69-be5d-a979b5e56cd5"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]

   here is the textual representation of the [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/specification.html) query just in case:

   ```
   entities.chairs.*.[name,id]
   ```
3. That's it, each time it will get the random name/id combination in form of `["OP55","36891051-1edf-46ea-a167-68d39a8a70f5"]`

   [image]

   which can be referenced as `${nameAndId}` where required

More information: [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)

Comment: Thank you Dimitri, but the result is coming with ["OP55","36891051-1edf-46ea-a167-68d39a8a70f5"], how to fetch only the values ? tried with ${}, but I want only OP55 and 36891051-1edf-46ea-a167-68d39a8a70f5